# Passing a struct method as an argument

Tags: go, reflection

I am not sure if I'm trying to exceed the limits of what Go will allow, but here is the context:
I have type called `Map` with a hefty number of helpful member functions, such as `Interpolate`, `Add`, and `Clear`. I also have a struct type, `Layered`, that contains several `Map`s.

```golang
type Map [][]float64

func (m Map) Interpolate(min, max float64) { ... }
func (m Map) Add(val float64) { ... }
func (m Map) Clear() { ... }

type Layered struct {
    data []Map
}
```

I would like to add a member function to `Layered` that accepts any member function of `Map` as an argument, and then calls it on all of its contained `Map`s. Something along the lines of:

```golang
func (l Layered) MapCall(callMe func(Map)) {
    for _, m := range l.data {
        callMe(m)
    }
}
```

This partially works, but only for member functions of `Map` that take no additional arguments, such as `Clear`. Is it at all possible to accept *any* member function of `Map` as an argument (along with its potential parameters in the form of an `...interface{}`), and then call the function, with its correct parameters, on all of the member `Map`s in a `Layered`? Something like this, for example:

```golang
func (l Layered) MapCall(callMe func(Map, ...interface{}), params ...interface{}) {
    for _, m := range l.data {
        callMe(m, params...)
    }
}
```

Comment: Interfaces don't make complex types (like your call me argument) polymorphic.  That will only accept functions that literally take the argument types `(Map, ...interface{})`.  You can just make the type of `callMe` as `interface{}` and it will accept any function, but you will need `reflect` to verify it and call it

Comment: Remember Go is statically typed, and interfaces are still concrete types (a struct containing type info, and pointer to the real data).  It's only that when using another value as an interface value, Go automatically boxes your original value into an interface value.

Comment: A more idiomatic Go solution would probably be 1. Instead of a `Layered` struct, just directly use `[]Map` values and use a `for range` loop at the call-site, instead of a helper function.  Or 2. Duplicate all the relevant `Map` methods for the `Layered` type also, with each method just being a `for range` loop calling the corresponding method on each `Map` and passing the parameters.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco Thank you! I was just beginning to try and implement it with what was going to be a very long switch statement of types, but what you said about duplicating all of the relevant `Map` functions makes a lot of sense to me. It's going to be a lot less of a pain to actually use those functions, too, once I'm done. I really appreciate the help; thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to be more functional than try to use interfaces.

I will provide an example using your `Interpolate` method.

You can start by defining a helper function for generating the operation:

```golang
func InterpolateOp(min, max float64) func(Map) {
    return func(m Map) {
        m.Interpolate(min, max)
    }
}
```

Another name that would match your `MapCall` function better is `MapInterpolate`.

Then, when using `MapCall` or creating lists of operations, you can use the same type you were using previously, namely `func(Map)`:

```golang
var l Layered
...
l.MapCall(InterpolateOp(2, 4))
```

The key to this solution is that the data is bound to the closure that makes up the function, which solves the original problem: not enough data to call the appropriate functions.

In your case, if there are so many methods that this is not worth doing, then you may look into code generation, since it is repetitive and easy. That is outside the scope of this question.

See also: https://dave.cheney.net/2016/11/13/do-not-fear-first-class-functions